# Old javascript and CSS file gets loaded

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am developing a simple php website using LAMP stack. Lot of the times, when I edit a javascript file, the new file with edits do not show up in chrome's debugger or in firebug. In the same way, when I edited a css file, the old css file gets loaded. I even renamed the old css file, still the old file gets loaded. Is it being cached somewhere? I even tried restarting the server.

Comment: Does it load properly when you hold down shift and press F5 or reload (that forces reload of everything)?

Comment: try to refresh using ctrl+f5 in your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and click reload to force Chrome to load all files from the server.

Comment: what if this happened on real end-users? We can't tell everyone to Shift+F5 everytime.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl + F5` is the shortcut for clearing cached files on the given page