# Can't call the correct CSS file for some reason

Tags: html, css

I'm having an extremely hard time trying to figure out why my css file is not being called. So I have a file named Style.css which was working perfectly fine until recently when I tried to modify some of the code and nothing was changing. I genuinely don't have the slightest clue as to why because everything was working perfectly fine when I first made the file.

The picture below shows both of my css files. The reason I have 2 files is because I was testing to see if the path I was calling was correct. Which I think I am calling to correct path, but I'm not getting the right results.

[Both css files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ZkQ.png)

As you can see when I call Stylee.css note the extra 'e'. Everything displays correctly with a blue border.

[Calling Stylee.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYgiw.png)

Then I call Style.css and I don't get a blue border. The border is black which is what the border color used to be in my old file, but I changed it to blue.

[Calling Style.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3zcp.png)

I absolutely promise this is not photo shopped I genuinely don't know why my old file is being called. I was hoping maybe someone knew why this might be the case. I made sure to go into my folder options and unhide hidden files and folders. Nothing came up. I kept changing the color in Stylee.css and the border kept changing. The style for the hover does work if that helps knowing.

I am aware that I can easily stop calling Style.css and call Stylee.css to make everything work, but I really don't want to settle for that. I'm coding to learn and kind of want to learn why this is happening.

Comment: Please post your code in code block, now is extremely hard to read

Comment: Sounds like your css files are cached. In that case you certainly will _not_ see any change if you alter them.

Comment: Sounds like browser cache to me. Do you have "Disable cache" checked on in your inspector?

Comment: I never used two words name for file, nor uppercase for css file. Probably not that but I would change it.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31772528/1016716, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23391074/1016716, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14928924/1016716, https://stackoverflow.com/q/9009856/1016716 etc.

Comment: is your style.css file in the same root folder as the index/html file. Good practice is to implement a structured file structure ie putting css files in root/css/style.css and js in root/js/script.js etc

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry everyone. Doing ctrl + F5 twice fixed the problem.

[Old CSS showing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772528/old-css-showing-up)

Solved my problem.